# PHP SOAP Error - Couldn't find <definitions>

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

Bit of a curly one I can't work out (I've not used SOAP an awful lot).

I have a WDSL web service I need to consume:
https://gist.github.com/aleayr/0dc4f26b0b9dd6ba7dae

But PHP is throwing a Fatal error when trying to consume it, saying

`PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't find <definitions> in 'http://path/to/ServiceManager.svc?wsdl' in C:\path\to\submit.php on line 37`

I note the actual XML tag has a wdsl namespace in front of it, is there any way to get PHP to recognise this?

Comment: I note that there is a space in the URL for the WSDL service I'm trying to consume. Would this make a difference? I've tried using the space, and %20 in there, same error.

Comment: As an alternative test, I put the URL into file_get_contents and echo'd it, with the space in the URL, it threw an error, with %20 it was able to read the remote site, so I know I can at least pull it down/connect, SOAP just doesn't appear to work correctly. Thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

I've the same error. This must be caused because there's no definition of the Action-URI. I've worked out like this:

```
public function testSOAPService()
{
$soap_action = "http://tempuri.org/XXXsomething/ActualURI";
$service = new SoapClient($this->wsdl); //WSDL defined before
$service->__setLocation($soap_action);
return $service->__getFunctions(); //you must see the functions of that service
}
```

At least for me this worked fine. Source [SoapClient::__setLocation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setlocation.php)